# getting errors when showing data on page using ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am adding a search functionality to my user admin page and I am using AJAX for search but I have not been able to show data on my page. It gives an error.

I have tried adding single quotation or double quotation on every side but it just give me an error every time

this is the controller function:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $output = '';
        $query = $request->get('query');
        if($query != '')
        {
            $data =User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
        }
        else
        {
            $data =User::orderBy('created_at' ,'desc')->get();
        }
        $total_row = $data->count();
        if($total_row > 0)
        {
            foreach($data as $merchant)//That how i am showing data on the page
            {
                $output .=
                "<tr>
                     <td>"{$users->name}"
                        "@if($users->allowded == 0)"  //I need to add these if else functionality to my code but these thing are giving error 
                        "@endif"
                    </td>
                    <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$users->permission->permission}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">
                            <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Salaried User
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 
                            <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him     Commesioned User
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 
                            <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Salaried and Commesionded User
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($users->user_status)
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"> 
                                <span style="padding-right: 10px;">Make Him Unpaid User
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        @else
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> 
                                <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Paid User
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        @endif  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @foreach($cashtransfer as $cash)
                            @if($cash->user_id == $users->id) 
                                {{ $cash->amount}}

                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if($users->allowded)
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                                <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Bloack User</span>
                            </a>
                        @else
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">
                                <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Allow User</span>
                            </a>
                         @endif
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
                            <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Delete User</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //This is The Out Variable which is taking data to the page
            $output = '
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data'  => $output,
            'total_data'  => $total_row
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

These Are the errors I am getting every time:

```
    // ->when($request->has('query'), function($q){
           //  $q->where('name','like','%'. request('query').'%');
           // })->get();
           $data =User::where('name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')->get();

          }
          else
          {
           $data =User::orderBy('created_at' ,'desc')->get();
           // $pagi = "<div> {$data->links()}</div>";
          }
          $total_row = $data->count();
          if($total_row > 0)
          {
           foreach($data as $merchant)
           {
                $output .= "
                    <tr>
        <td>"{$users->name}"
        "@if($users->allowded == 0)"

        "@endif"
        </td>
        <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->permission->permission}}</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Salaried User</span></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Commesioned User</span></a><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"> <span style="padding-right: 16px;">Make Him Salaried and Commesionded User</span></a></td>



      <td>
        @if($users->user_status)

        <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"> <span style="padding-right: 10px;">Make Him Unpaid User</span></a>
        @else
```

Why can't I just publish it?
I keep getting errors like I need more details

Comment: Please check out how to ask page and also can you please share your error messages.

Comment: I am having error like unexpected '""  on line this and that and when i clear first error then it show Unexpected @ and then Unexpected if how to solve this problem??

Comment: Acronym capitalization; grammar; noise reduction; layout.

It's still very unclear where the error happens

Comment: How can i post a image in here so you can an idea of my error or can you contact me on some social media

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use blade inside normal strings. You have to use normal PHP to compose the output:

```php
foreach($data as $merchant)
{
    $optionalOutput = $users->allowded == 0 ? 'output if true' : 'output if false';
    $output .= "<tr>
                     <td>{$users->name}
                        {$optionalOutput}
                    </td>";
    // ...
}
```

Or you could move the code to a blade view:

```php
foreach($data as $merchant)
{
    $output .= view('path.to.view', [$merchant, $users])->render();
}
```

Comment: ok so if i will past my data in that view in laravel blade formate then it will work fine?

Comment: so i can do all my if else functionality before output cariable and it will work fine?

Comment: Yes. You can use almost the same code you have, just remove the quotes around `@if()` etc. and put all variables into double curly braces: `{{ $users->name }}`

Comment: This is not working both the ways are not working i have tried them

Comment: when i use if statement ajax does not show any data and when i inspect it it says 505 error